# Logstash missing JAVA_HOME

Tags: elasticsearch, environment-variables, logstash

I'm new to Logstash everytime I try to run it I have the following error:

> Could not find any executable java binary. Please install java in your PATH or set JAVA_HOME.

When I do echo `$JAVA_HOME` I have the following:

```
/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you are probably using a "manually installed" java. You can install openjdk (elastic runs fine in it) using your distribution package manager, then this variable is set up automatically and you dont have to worry about exporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, I removed all Logstash files and reinstalled open JDK. it worked for me. But I did not face that kind of error for the previous version, and another thing is there is an inbuilt JDK in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to export the `JAVA_HOME` variable. Given by your information, this should do it for you:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/"
```

If you type this command in a Linux Terminal, which I assume you use, the following Logstash is capable to find the java executable, which it needs to run logstash.